# In Rails how can i restore my indexes for my tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, azure, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails app, and originally I had the database setup in SQL Server locally.  Recently, I moved it up to Azure SQL Server, and have just copied down the changes locally again.  When I imported the database down all the tables and data replicated down, but it seems all my primary keys and indexes are gone.  Is it possible to run a rake command or rails command to add these keys/indexes back?

Comment: How did you restore the database?

Comment: vee, Through SSIS using Import Data from the context menu on the New DB I created. Then I connected to the database with a ADO.net connection string and used the rest of the defaults for the Wizard.

Comment: I do not have an Azure SQL server to test this but you could use `backup` and `restore` from the `All Tasks` menu in SQL Server.  Import/Export data does not include the keys and index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a bacpac file from my Azure database and imported it as a data-tier application within SQL Server.

**Create BACPAC File**

1. Go to your Azure Portal.
2. Select "Storage" from the menu and create a new storage. I just gave it a url and clicked create storage account.  It will take a minute for the new storage to be created.
3. Once the storage is created, go to SQL Databases. Open the database you wish to create a bacpac file from and then at the bottom of the portal select 'Export'. And follow the export wizard, by selecting your storage account and providing your credentials.

**SSMS Import Data-Tier Application**

1. Right click your Databases folder under your connection in Object Explorer.
2. Click "Import Data-Tier Application" and follow the wizard. When you get to "Import Settings" select the bacpac file you downloaded from your Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a auto-generated SQL script file (through rake db:create, rake db:migrate) etc, and this file usually is available in 'db/structure.sql'. You can run that script - you may need to manually remove the CREATE TABLE statements, but retain ALTER SEQUENCE, ALTER TABLE, CREATE INDEX statements.